# Can i use PageFactory.initElements to create an object while WebDriver isn't direct (yet) to the page where the WebElements are stored

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, pom.xml, pageobjects

My question is about Page Object Model in selenuim.
I will try to explain myself by an example
Let's say i have 2 site.
The first one ([www.aaa.com](http://www.aaa.com)) that has a button that clicking on him take us to the second url ([www.bbb.com](http://www.bbb.com))
For both pages i have a class (AAA,BBB) with the elements that are relevant for each of them.
Now i have the following code:

```
@BeforeClass
public void openBrowser() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.aaa.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    AAA a= PageFactory.initElements(driver, AAA.class);
    BBB b = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BBB.class);
    
}
```

My question is: does the last line of code:         **BBB b = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BBB.class);** will throw an exception since the object driver is currently set to work with *http://www.aaa.com* and therefore when trying to find elements from **http://www.bbb.com** we will get an exception saying: "NoSuchElement"?
According to my try it doesn't happen but it is very surprise for me and i really want to understand how does it work correctly? I was sure that the last line should be written only after moving to the second page (http://www.bbb.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PageFactory.initElements` will not throw `NoSuchElement` exception. The reason is, `initElements` will not do `findElement` call but will initialize element object with element [proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

Comment: can you explain shortly for a beginner what do you mean when saying element proxy?

Comment: end user doesn't need to do anything. However regarding proxy you can refer java documentation  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html